# MySQL Server can't be installed

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, redhat

I've been trying to install MySQL 5.6.31.
When installing it with the `rpm` command:

```
rpm -ivh MySQL-server-5.6.31-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

The process start but doesn't finish and no error presented:

```
warning: MySQL-server-5.6.31-1.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
Preparing...                       ################################# [100%]
Updating / installing...
1:MySQL-server-5.6.31-1.el7        ################################# [100%]
```

Tried downloading another rpm, but nothing works..

Any solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Remove mysql completely:

```
yum remove `yum list installed | grep mysql`
```

and the reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use # yum localinstall MySQL-server-5.6.31-1.el7.x86_64.rpm